# Android Threaded Canvas problems with Sensors

Tags: java, android, eclipse, multithreading, canvas

I'm having some problems with creating a SensorManager and outputting the values of the accelerometer on the screen with a green circle that moves when you tilt the phone. It's an example from Sam's teach yourself android game programming in 24 hours by Jonathan Harbour. I have checked and double checked and my code is identical to his. Basically, it's a Custom SurfaceHolder canvas that uses a Thread to repeatedly update. Here is the main activity, Game (yes, I know, the imports are messy):

```
    package com.example.sensordemo;

import java.util.*;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.renderscript.Float2;
import android.renderscript.Float3;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.Window;

public class Game extends Activity implements SensorEventListener
{
    DrawView drawView;
    SensorManager sensors;
    Sensor accel;
    Float3 accelMotion = new Float3();
    List<Sensor> sensorList;

    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        drawView = new DrawView(this);
        setContentView(drawView);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        sensors = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accel = sensors.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

        sensorList = sensors.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);

        Log.i("Game", "onCreate()");
    }

    @Override public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
    {
        switch (event.sensor.getType()) 
        {
        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            accelMotion.x = event.values[0];
            accelMotion.y = event.values[1];
            accelMotion.z = event.values[2];
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1)
    {

    }

    @Override public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i("Game", "resume");

        drawView.resume();
        sensors.registerListener(this, accel, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        drawView.pause();
        sensors.unregisterListener(this);
        Log.i("Game", "pause");
    }

    public class DrawView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable
    {
        Thread gameloop = null;
        SurfaceHolder surface = null;
        volatile boolean running = false;
        AssetManager assets = null;
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        Float2 center;

        public DrawView(Context context)
        {
            super(context);
            surface = getHolder();
            assets = context.getAssets();
            Log.i("Game", "draw view made");
        }

        public void resume()
        {
            running = true;
            gameloop = new Thread(this);
            gameloop.start();
            Log.i("Game", "drawview resumed");
        }

        public void pause()
        {
            running = false;
            Log.i("DrawView", "pausing");
            while(true)
            {
                try
                {
                    gameloop.join();
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e)
                {

                }
            }
        }

        @Override public void run()
        {
            while(running)
            {
                if(!surface.getSurface().isValid()) continue;

                Canvas canvas = surface.lockCanvas();

                canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

                Log.i("Game", "running");

                float width = canvas.getWidth();
                float height = canvas.getHeight();
                center = new Float2(width / 2.0f, height / 2.0f);

                Float2 ratio = new Float2(width / 10.0f, height / 10.0f);
                float x = center.x - accelMotion.x * ratio.x;
                float y = center.y + accelMotion.y * ratio.y;
                paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                canvas.drawCircle(x,  y,  100,  paint);

                paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                paint.setTextSize(24);
                canvas.drawText("Accelerometer Demo", 10, 20, paint);
                String s = "X=" + Math.round(accelMotion.x) + ", Y=" + accelMotion.y + ", Z=" + accelMotion.z;
                canvas.drawText(s,  10,  50,  paint);
                canvas.drawText("Model: " + accel.getVendor(), 10, 80, paint);

                surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(20);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know what the problem is. The Screen goes all white and nothing happens (The thingy at the top with notifications is still visible). Also, it crashes the phone sometimes. It's a htc 1 M7 running android 5.0.1. This is the output from Logcat:

```
06-17 21:47:40.760: W/asset(14951): Copying FileAsset 0xb85d1e68 (zip:/data/app/com.example.sensordemo-1/base.apk:/resources.arsc) to buffer size 157568 to make it aligned.
06-17 21:47:40.770: E/Typeface(14951): SANS_LOC file not found.
06-17 21:47:40.790: I/Game(14951): draw view made
06-17 21:47:41.090: E/SensorManager(14951): uid = 10196
06-17 21:47:41.100: E/SensorManager(14951): uid = 10196
06-17 21:47:41.100: I/Game(14951): onCreate()
06-17 21:47:41.110: I/Game(14951): resume
06-17 21:47:41.110: I/Game(14951): drawview resumed
06-17 21:47:41.110: I/SensorManager(14951): registerListenerImpl: listener = com.example.sensordemo.Game@110bc638, sensor = {Sensor name="BOSCH BMA250 3-axis Accelerometer", vendor="BOSCH", version=1, type=1, maxRange=39.2266, resolution=0.038307227, power=0.1, minDelay=10000}, delay = 200000, handler = null
06-17 21:47:41.130: D/Atlas(14951): Validating map...
06-17 21:47:41.150: E/Typeface(14951): SANS_LOC file not found.
06-17 21:47:41.150: I/DrawView(14951): pausing
```

I would just like to note that pause is called straight away, not when I tab out of the app. Exiting and entering the app does not make the programme continue, it just stops. Nothing happens on the screen apart from it turning white, going into landscape mode and nothing else. Sorry for the long post, but I have no idea what is going on, and so I have tried to include all relevant sources. Any suggestions, ideas and, of course, any solutions you have please comment or reply below. All help is appreciated. If you require any other files I will add them, just tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with the same book and had the same problem... ran across your question looking for an answer, so I thought I'd backtrack and pass along what I found (after MUCH pain and suffering lol)

The problem seems to be in the pause procedure (not the onPause, the pause in DrawView). I think it was that the thread was not properly stopped, and they tried to re-start the same thread again in the resume procedure.

After changing it to the following code, everything seems to work fine.

```
public void pause() {
        gameloop.interrupt();
        running = false;
        try{
            gameloop.join();
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
```